# Creating a array from a linked list and sorting that array C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, linked-list

Someone told me that the best way to sort a linked list is to copy that linked list into a array and sort that array.

```
#define SIZE 7000
```

So my linked list:

```
typedef struct no{

    char *nome;
    int count;
    struct no * prox;
}*link;
```

My array:

```
typedef struct MyArray 
{
    char name[141];
    int count;
}MyArray;

MeuArray v[SIZE];
```

Now my create array function:

```
void create_array()
{
link tmp = head;
int cont = 0;
int i;

while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(v[cont].nome, tmp->nome);
        v[cont].count = tmp->count;
        tmp = tmp->prox;
        cont++;
    }
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    printf("%s %d\n", v[i].nome, v[i].count);
}
```

Don't know if this is correct.
Now I don't know which is the best/fastest. qsort or other.
If qsort:

```
int compare(struct MeuArray *elem1, struct MeuArray *elem2)
{
if ( elem1->count < elem2->count)
  return -1;

else if (elem1->count > elem2->count)
  return 1;

else
{
    if (strcmp(elem1->name, elem2->name) > 1)
        return 1;
    else
         return -1;
 }
}
```

I also tried this way (sort my linked list):

```
void insertionSort(link current)
{   
link head = current;
link inserP = head;
current = current->prox;
while (current != NULL)
{
    inserP = head;

    while (inserP != current)
     {
        if (inserP->count > current->count)
        {
            int temp = current->count;
            current->count = inserP->count;
             inserP->count = temp;
        }
        else /* if (inserP->count < current->count) */
            inserP = inserP->prox;

        /*else
            {
                if (strcmp(inserP->name, current->name) > 0)
                {
                    char temp2 = strcpy(temp2, current->name);
                    strcpy(current->name, inserP->name);
                    strcpy(inserP->name, temp2);
                 }
                 else
                     inserP = inserP->prox;
            } */
         }
    }
    current = current->prox;
}
```

with:

```
link head = NULL;
```

Any help apreciated.

EDIT

I in qsort I want to compare first by count then by name.
Problem is that I can only sort by count.
How to sort by name after?

Code:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{

MeuArray *MeuArrayA = (MeuArray *)a;
MeuArray *MeuArrayB = (MeuArray *)b;

if ( MeuArrayB->count > MeuArrayA->count )
    return 1;
else if ( MeuArrayB->count < MeuArrayA->count )
    return -1;
else
{
    if (strcmp(MeuArrayB->nome, MeuArrayA->nome))
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;  
}
}
```

Comment: Debugger......................

Comment: What are the contents of your linklist ? Why does it have a count variable ?

Comment: Your question misses a question ;-) What is your problem? Does the code produce an error or incorrect result? What input values have you tried?

Comment: store pointer to array of pointer. then qsort.

Comment: My question is. If this is how to create an array from a linked list and how to implement a qsort. Or there is a better way/faster way.

Comment: Imagine that I write: a asas #asas. What my program does is save #asas in the linked list. So the name is #asas and count is the number of times it appears. In this case only one.

Comment: `Someone told me that the best way to sort a linked list is to copy that linked list into a array and sort that array.` Tell that someone that (s)he is wrong. The *natural* way for sorting Linked Lists is mergesort.

Comment: So that's the best/fastest way to do it?

Comment: It is the simplest. And it does not need O(N) addtional storage. And it will not be slower than qsort in this case. Plus: you do not need to know the number of elements in advance.

Comment: @Quick: If your code is working and you want to know how to make it better (i.e. you don't have a problem you can't solve but want suggestions on how to improve your code) you could post it to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the option of not having to use an array, but still want a fast sort, here is an example of a bottom up merge sort for linked list, using a small (26 to 32) array of pointers to nodes. This is usually the fastest algorithm and typically how C++ std::list::sort() is implemented. On my system (Intel 2600K, 3.4 ghz), it can sort a linked list with 4 million nodes in less than a second.

```
typedef struct NODE_{
struct NODE_ * next;
int data;
}NODE;

/* prototype */
NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2);

/* sort list using array of pointers to first nodes of list   */
/* aList[i] = NULL or ptr to list with 2 to the power i nodes */

#define NUMLISTS 32                 /* size of array */
NODE * SortList(NODE *pList)
{
NODE * aList[NUMLISTS];             /* array of lists */
NODE * pNode;
NODE * pNext;
int i;
    if(pList == NULL)               /* check for empty list */
        return NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)   /* zero array */
        aList[i] = NULL;
    pNode = pList;                  /* merge nodes into array */
    while(pNode != NULL){
        pNext = pNode->next;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i] != NULL); i++){
            pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
            aList[i] = NULL;
        }
        if(i == NUMLISTS)           /* don't go past end of array */
            i--;
        aList[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;
    }
    pNode = NULL;                   /* merge array into one list */
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)
        pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}

/* mergelists -  compare uses src2 < src1           */
/* instead of src1 <= src2 to be similar to C++ STL */

NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst = NULL;                  /* destination head ptr */
NODE **ppDst = &pDst;               /* ptr to head or prev->next */
    if(pSrc1 == NULL)
        return pSrc2;
    if(pSrc2 == NULL)
        return pSrc1;
    while(1){
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            pSrc2 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc2->next));
            if(pSrc2 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc1;
                break;
            }
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            if(pSrc1 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pDst;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to sort the link list then you don't need to convert it to array. you can do it in link list in efficient manner

```
while(t1!=NULL)
 {
  count++;
  t1=t1->ptr;
 }
 for(i=0;i<count;i++)
  {
   t1=START;
   for(j=0;j<count-i-1;j++)
    {
      if(t1->info>(t1->ptr)->info)
       {
 int temp=t1->info;
 t1->info=(t1->ptr)->info;
 (t1->ptr)->info=temp;
       }
       t1=t1->ptr;
    }
  }
```

which used bubble sort
for more info [click here](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/2016/04/c-program-to-implement-sorting-in-link.html)

Comment: If I want to use it, how do I change it so it orders from count and then by nome?  And what is START?

Comment: IDK what `START` is.